# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "__products", referenced from:

Tags: xcode, linker, compiler-errors

I could use some help on the following errors I keep getting when trying to run my project.

My project is already published with an In App Purchase.
In my newest version I try to incorporate IAP in another view controller but when I want to run I get two Apple Mach-O Linker Error and a Dsymutil Error as well.

I may have updated Xcode(to Version 4.6 (4H127)) since my last published version, but I'm not sure.

Some things I've checked already:

- Link Binary With Binaries still seems to include all neccessary frameworks;
- Compile Sources seems to include all my .m files;
- I can't find the __products anywhere in my code (_products I can find thoug...: I made a global variable with that name (was a local variable before))
- I tried running on simulator and a device as well.

Global variable is declared in .h file which is imported in view controller in which it is needed:
extern NSArray *_products;

I'm not sure of my external frameworks/libraries can cause any trouble. They worked fine before: TestFlight, Appirater, CHCSVParser.

The errors:

> Ld "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen" normal i386
>       cd "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Documents/Xcode projects/Mijn Kinderen"
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Documents/Xcode projects/Mijn Kinderen/TestFlightSDK1-1" "-L/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Documents/Xcode projects/Mijn Kinderen" -F/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Intermediates/Mijn Kinderen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.build/Objects-normal/i386/Mijn Kinderen.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework StoreKit -framework MessageUI -lz -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -lTestFlight -o "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "__products", referenced from:
      -[MKGebeurtenissenViewController voegToeGebeurtenis:] in MKGebeurtenissenViewController.o
      -[MKGebeurtenissenViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in MKGebeurtenissenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController productPurchased:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController voegKindToe:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
      -[MKGebeurtenissenViewController voegToeGebeurtenis:] in MKGebeurtenissenViewController.o
      -[MKGebeurtenissenViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in MKGebeurtenissenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController productPurchased:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
      -[MKKinderenViewController voegKindToe:] in MKKinderenViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

GenerateDSYMFile "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app.dSYM" "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen"
    cd "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Documents/Xcode projects/Mijn Kinderen"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen" -o "/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app.dSYM"

error: unable to open executable '/Users/jaspervandermaarel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mijn_Kinderen-dglsdifvjduysjbpixoiuyaekgky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen'

Comment: can you edit your question to show how the global variable "`_products`" is declared?  hopefully it's not just an "`extern`".

Comment: I'm afraid it is, see my edit.
Is this bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that "`extern`" is bad, you just need to declare the ***real*** "`NSArray`" at the top of some .m file somewhere otherwise the object hasn't really been allocated anywhere.

So if you declare your "`extern`" variable in a .h file, declare the real variable at the top of the .m file that supports that .h file.

E.G.

```
NSArray * _products;
```

before the "`@implementation`" bit.  And make sure you *do* alloc & init that variable somewhere in your .m file.

Comment: Thanks; that got rid of all three errors!
I declared it inside the @implementation bit. Why is the extra underscore added to the symbol causing the problem?